# Java Exception when creating or writing files on mounted HDFS

Tags: java, hdfs, mount

Now I am working with a project that written using java,and I hava the need to use hdfs to storage the files it created.So I mounted HDFS to local filesystem,but I got some problerms using this mounted HDFS.When the program creating or writing files to the mounted HDFS,I got exceptions.So I made a demo to test,and get the errors as well.The code are like this below:

```
    package test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        File f = new File("/mnt/hdfs/test");
        try {
            System.out.println(f.createNewFile());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

The exceptions are here:

```
java.io.IOException: Unknown error 524
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:883)
    at test.Test.main(Test.java:15)
```

I have the rw permission to the mounted HDFS,and I can successfully create directories using jdk api(not the hadoop api) ，now my question is that if I can create or write to files via JDK API? Is anyone have successfully done this?And if so,what should I do to make it possible?

Comment: HDFS is not POSIX-compliant. That's probably why.

Comment: why do you want to store something in a directory that you actually want to serve as your HDFS??

Comment: Thank you for your help.The program was developed to store clinical images and videos.And it was designed to store files to local file system via java api （just like the demo I wrote）.As a result of Hadoop's high capacity and robust, we mounted it to centos as a local directory,but I got that problem.Do you mean that the mounted HDFS is not support the way I used to store files? If so,what should be the proper way to do that？Appreciate for more help.